# How can I update a field in a document when another is created in cloud firestore?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm new to flutter and firebase and I'm creating a web app using those. I want to create a firebase cloud function that updates another document when another is added/created. I have two documents; users and groups. In the users document there's an array called groups that would have the uids of the groups that the user is in and in the groups document there's an array called members with uids of the users in the group:

[image]

[image]

**Question**:
**How can I add the group uid to the specific user's group array that are mentioned in the group member's array when a new group is created?**

I'm a total noob with type script so I'm not sure of what I'm doing, but here's what I started with:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';

const admin=require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

export const updateUserGroups= functions.database.ref('/groups/{groupUID}/members').onCreate(()=>{});
```

I'm not to sure how the groupUID would get to the function after creation. I'd guess I'd have to pass it somehow(I'm using flutter..so I'm not to sure how that would work.)? If anyone could help, I'd appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, you've stared off on the wrong foot, since `functions.database` is used for building functions that work with Realtime Database, not Firestore.  You will want to use `functions.firestore` for that.  I strongly suggest starting with the documentation. https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found a solution:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';

"use strict"

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
const db = admin.firestore();

export const updateUserGroups = functions.firestore.document('groups/{groupUID}').onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
    const groupUID=snapshot.id;
    const groupData = snapshot.data();
    for (let userUID of groupData['members']) { 
        db.collection('users').doc(userUID).update({groups: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove(null)})
        db.collection('users').doc(userUID).update({groups: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(groupUID)})
    }
});
```

Just had to do a little digging. The comment by Doug helped me figure out what to look at, so thanks Doug!